# buttons for sending a 1 byte character to an ip address

Tags: python, ip

I am new to python and I am looking for a way to send a 1 byte character (for example: the letter "D") to an ip address. This is used to control a robot so all I need are forward, backward, left and right. I've done some research online and it suggests using sockets to connect to the ip address but it seems kind of confusing to me. I have made 4 buttons in my webpage already but I am not too sure on how to make the webpage send out the signal to the ip address when the user click on the button (for example: if the user press the "right" button, the webpage will send a one byte character "r" to the ip address)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

ps would there be any big difference between the networking method i use? like between wifi and 3G

Comment: forgot to mention that i will be using tcp/ip as client

Comment: possible duplicate of [Injecting raw TCP packets with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912123/injecting-raw-tcp-packets-with-python)

Comment: It's unclear what this has to do with Python. Are you using a Python web framework. If so, please specify which framework this is - it could be relevant.

Comment: i am making a web page, i was just thinking of using python but any language would work for me.

Comment: Don't bother with the Web page yet - get it working from the command-line directly first, then worry about the front end.

Answer (score 1):

Sockets are easy, especially in Python! :)

This is a simple program to send a single letter to some ip-address:

```
import socket

# Each address on the Internet is identified by an ip-address
# and a port number.
robot_ip_address = "192.168.0.12"  # Change to applicable
robot_port       = 3000            # Change to applicable

# Create a socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect to somewhere...
s.connect((robot_ip_address, robot_port))

# Send one character to the socket
s.send('D')

# Close the socket after use
s.close()
```

The robot of course needs a similar program to receive commands:

```
import socket

robot_port = 3000  # Change to applicable

# Create a socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# "Bind" it to all ip-addresses on the local host, and a specific port
s.bind(("", robot_port))

# Tell the socket to listen for connections
s.listen(5)

while True:
    # Wait for a new connection
    print "Waiting for connection..."
    (c, c_addr) = s.accept()

    print "New connection from: ", c_addr

    while True:
        try:
            command = c.recv(1)
        except socket.error, e:
            print "Error: %r" % e
            break;

        if command == 'D':
            # Do something for the 'D' command
            print "Received command 'D'"
        elif command == '':
            print "Connection closed"
            break
        else:
            print "Unknown command, closing connection"
            break

    c.close()
```

As you can see, there is very little code to write and understand. You don'r really have to understand most of how networking and TCP/IP works, just that a socket is used to communicate over the Internet. :)

Duplicate the first program, one for each button, and modify what is sent to the server. Then you have four programs sending different commands, to be connected to your buttons.

Read more on Python sockets [here](http://docs.python.org/howto/sockets.html), and [here](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html).